# overriding a javascript function's return statement

Tags: javascript, metaprogramming

Assume I have a js function. From some other point in the program, I want to run its code, but not its return statement. In its place, I would like to run some other return statement that references the variables in the scope of the original function.

Is there a way to do this, other than loading up the function source, replacing the return, and using eval on the result? Minimal modification of the original is possible, though it should not affect the original's performance by adding e.g. an extra function call.

Comment: Sorry, on mobile phone, although I can post some in an hour or so.

Comment: #1 - you can use AOP to change the return, but you will not have access to internal variables.  #2 - you can use new Function on the .toString() of the original function, interpolating your new code.  You'll have full access but this is considered garbage code.

Answer (score 3):

You could try something like this, but I'm not sure it meets your conditions.

**Edit**: Fixed to work in jsfiddle

```
// Modified to set all "shared" variables as "members" of the function.
var test = function() {
    test.val = "one";
    test.val2 = "two";
    return 1;   
}

// Using different result
function test2() {
    test();
    return test.val2;
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't you have to call test as a constructor for that to work?

Comment: @AdamRackis When you don't call `test` as a constructor then `this === window`.

Comment: I'm surprised this answer got two up-votes as it is both incorrect and not what the op was asking for..

Comment: @dzejkej - the code as posted in the answer doesn't work.. see http://jsfiddle.net/hUaJD/

Comment: @dzejkej - yes, exactly.  So the function would add val and val2 to the window object, and return 1.  How could you then say `test.val2;`?

Comment: You are both right, sorry. I somehow thought you are referring to the "this.val". I was blind.

Comment: @MikyDinescu:  How do you know what the OP was asking for (besides the question text)?  Also, the idea is sound if you implement it correctly.  Note the "something like this" in the answer.

Comment: @AdamRackis: How did you determine that?  I can run this just fine and test.val2 is NOT undefined.

Comment: @John - not sure, just ran it again and it does work.  My apologies.  +1 in 25 minutes :)

Comment: @JohnFisher: From the body of the question: "Minimal modification of the original is possible, though it should not affect the original's performance by adding e.g. an extra function call". Now, granted, an extra function call is not really going to affect performance as much as the OP probably assumes, but still.. that's what I based my comment on.

Comment: @MikyDinescu: Where's the extra function call?

Comment: @JohnFisher: Yous solution uses test2() as a wrapper for test(), does it not?  That's basically one extra function call.  P.S. The part about your answer being incorrect is no longer applicable as you've modified your answer since.

Comment: @MikyDinescu:  How do you propose that he call test() and get "run some other return statement that references the variables in the scope of the original function" without wrapping test() in a different function?

Comment: @JohnFisher: As I said in my answer, I don't know of a way to accomplish what he's asking for exactly. If you remove some of the constraints from his question then your *modified* answer is a way, and some of the others too. Please don't take this the wrong way, but I believe it's important to answer the question that was asked. And of course, to get a good answer you have to ask a good question. Finally, if you believe the OP's question doesn't really reflect his true intentions - clarify with comments, then answer the clarified question (or qualify your answer with a disclaimer); my 2c.

Comment: @MikyDinescu: It looks like we're just disagreeing about the interpretation of the OP's words.  You see an exclusion of additional functions.  I do not.  (It doesn't really matter anyway, since the OP accepted an answer already.)

Answer (score 1):

You can introduce a callback function that will get called if available otherwise "standard" value will be returned.

```
function test(callback) {
  // ...
  return callback ? callback.call(this) : /* original value returned */ "xyz";
}

test(function() { /* "this" is same as in test() */ });
```

EDIT:

If you want to pass variables inside callback then you just list them in the `.call()` function.

**Example:**

```
function test(callback) {
  var a = 4;
  var b = 2;
  // ...
  return callback ? callback.call(this, a, b) : a * b;
}

test(); // 8
test(function(a, b) { return a + b; }); // 6
```

See [**this fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/J5BmC/).

Answer (score 1):

Unless you're able to restructure your methods to accommodate a [callback](http://jsfiddle.net/6je8n/2/) or introduce some other parameter-based logic-flow (not an option for 3rd party code), you're out of luck.

Here's a callback sample ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6je8n/2/), credit to [dzejkej's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8362053/621962:))

```
function foo(callback) {
    var x = 2;   
    // pass your values into the callback
    return callback ? callback.call(this, x) : x * 2;
}
document.write(foo());
document.write("<hr/>");
// specify the parameters for your callback
document.write(foo(function(x){ return x * 4;}) );
```

Comment: Have you read the question? "Is there a way to do this, **other than (...) source, replacing the return**, and using eval on the result? Minimal modification of the original is possible"

Comment: I can modify the original, as long as I keep its performance stable.

Comment: I put an example into mine answer and then realized you have done the same earlier :). I will leave it there to have more complete answer. But +1 to you.

Answer (score 0):

I think you really misunderstand the concept of *return statement*. The return statement of a function will simply return a value, or an object, or undefined if there is no return *parameter* specified.

If all you're trying to do is execute a function but "not its return statement" than you would just invoke the function and not do anything with the returned value/object:

However, if what you mean is that you would like to execute a function but not execute the "parameter" to its return statement then that literally means to selectively execute an arbitrary portion of the body of a function. And as far as I know that is not possible (without using reflection to get the function definition, modify the definition, and then dynamically invoking the modified version - which you said you didn't want to do).

Comment: Depends on whether you count the parameter as part of the statement, but your second option is correct. Will try to edit the question appropriately

Comment: @AlexandrosMarinos - do you have control over the original function (i.e. do you have the option to rewrite the function)? Obviously if you do - that changes the things you could do to *simulate* the behavior you're looking for.

Comment: Yes, I do have that option, but am limited by the need to keep its performance the same. What are you thinking of?

Comment: @AlexandrosMarinos  Add a parameter to the function that would enable/disable executing the portion of code that you don't want executed. Adding something like that in surely would not impact the performance of the function too much (it would essentially just be another branch condition)

Answer (score 0):

Provided that you would keep variables of the outer scope function within a single object, you could try something like the following:

```
function original(a, b, c, rep) {
    var data = {};

    // Do some fancy stuff but make sure to keep everything under data
    data.a = a.replace(/foo/, 'bar');
    ...

    if ( Object.prototype.toString.call(rep) === '[object Function]' )
        return rep.call(data);

    return data;
}

function replacement() {
    return 'foo' + this.a;
}

// Now let's make use of both the original and the replacement ...
console.log(original('foo', x, y)); // => {a: "bar", b: ...}

console.log(original('foo', x, y, replacement)); // => {a: "foobar", b: ...}
```

Hope, it's what you where asking for.
cheers